# Issue of Dense columns in the formulation

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, solver

I'm working on a price-selection model where we need to identify price point for each time-period (could be day/week). Objective of the model is to figure out optimal price-point for each time-point to optimize revenue from all products. One price-point selected applies to all products
$$
\begin{align*}
&\mathcal{P} \quad \text{set of products (indexed by $p$)}\\
&\mathcal{T} \quad \text{set of time-periods (indexed by $t$)}\\
&\mathcal{K} \quad \text{set of price-points (indexed by $k$)}\\
&D_{p,t,k} \quad \text{demand of product $p$ in time-period $t$ at price-point $k$}  \\
&R_{p,t,k} \quad \text{Revenue associated with product $p$ for time-period $t$ at price-point $k$}  \\
&
\end{align*}
$$
Binary variable $z_{t,k}$ equals 1 if price-point $k$ is selected for time-period $t$. As same price applies for all products, objective is to maximize revenue i.e.
$$
Maximize \quad \sum_{p,t,k} R_{p,t,k} \cdot q_{p,t,k}
$$
Also, main constraint is to identify quantity sold $q_{p,t,k}$ for each product $p$ at time-period $t$ if $k$ price-point is selected and is given by
$$
q_{p,t,k} \le D_{p,t,k} \cdot z_{t,k}
$$
Only one price point to be selected per time-period
$$
\sum_{k} z_{t,k}=1
$$
Total inventory sold is less than initial inventory $I_{p}$
$$
\sum_{t,k} q_{p,t,k} \le I_{p}
$$
Also, there are some side constraints on price changes from one time-period to another. With this formulation, while solving as MIP (root-relaxation solve), it shows dense columns in the logs which is leading to high computational time for a larger product case. Snippet of log is provided below:

```
Barrier statistics:
 Dense cols : 74
 AA' NZ     : 1.509e+06
 Factor NZ  : 8.201e+06 (roughly 400 MBytes of memory)
 Factor Ops : 2.808e+08 (less than 1 second per iteration)
 Threads    : 4
```

I'm looking for alternate formulation to avoid these dense columns which is primarily caused by inventory constraints.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I have edited.

Comment: Does it still take long to solve without the side constraints?

Comment: Yes. It takes time even without side constraints.

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for Benders decomposition with $z$ as the master variables.

Comment: Have you tried not including subscript $k$ on variable $q$? In other words, let $q_{p,t}$ be the amount of $p$ sold at time $t$. The inventory constraint will be sparser, though the demand constraint will be denser (RHS will be a sum). It will reduce your variable count. Whether that's an overall improvement is an empirical question.

Comment: @prubin How do you avoid the fact that $R$ and $D$ both depend on $p,t,k$?

Comment: @RobPratt Demand is easy: $q_{p,t} \le \sum_k D_{p,t,k} z_{t,k}.$ (This is what I meant by "RHS will be a sum".) Revenue will require a new continuous variable ($w_{p,t,k}$) and constraints $w_{p,t,k} \le R_{p,t,k} q_{p,t}$ and $w_{p,t,k} \le R_{p,t,k}Q z_{t,k}$ (where $Q$ is an upper bound on $q_{p,t}$). The objective is $\sum_{p,t,k} w_{p,t,k}.$ Bad news: more (continuous) variables and constraints. Good news: the extra constraints are sparse.

Comment: @prubin OK, I thought you were proposing to somehow reduce the variable count.

Comment: @RobPratt I did say that, which was a mistake. There would be fewer $q$ variables, and I did note that the demand constraints wouldn't be a problem, but I forgot about the objective function.

Comment: RobPratt Thanks for suggesting Benders and I haven't tried using such decomposition on this problem. Will try to implement it.                                                   @prubin: Thanks for suggesting alternate formulation. One clarification on the constraint $w_{p,t,k} \le R_{p,t,k} \cdot Q \cdot z_{t,k}$, Isn't this constraint also leading to same dense columns? Please suggest if I'm missing something.

Comment: There would be one instance of that constraint for each combination of $p$, $t$ and $k,$ and each constraint would only have two nonzeros, which is pretty sparse.

Comment: Dense columns seems primarily coming from $z_{t,k}$ column and number of entries in the column will be total $p$ for a combinations of (t,k). I tried with the suggested formulation and observed solver showing same number of dense cols. Please suggest if I'm missing something.